# SOAP Endpoint must return String value

Tags: web-services, spring-boot, soap, soapui

I'm new in SOAP technology,

I would like simply to test this endpoint :

My java file :

```
@Endpoint
public class DestinataireEndpoints {

    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://www.opensolution.com/";

    @Autowired
    private DestinataireService destinataireService;    

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "LiaisonResponse")
    @ResponsePayload
    public String LiaisonResponse() {
        return "SAMPLE";
    }
```

My xsd file:

```
<xs:element name="LiaisonResponse">
       <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="LiaisonResult" type="xs:string" />
         </xs:sequence>
       </xs:complexType>
     </xs:element>
```

This is my configuration file:

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class SoapConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
    }

    @Bean(name = "destinataire")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema statesSchema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("StatesPort");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://www.opensolution.com/");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(statesSchema);
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

    @Bean
    public XsdSchema statesSchema() {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("destinataire.xsd"));
    }
```

I use SoapUI for testing and this is what I get :

[image]

What is missing ?

Comment: You have to return an XML payload not a String.

Comment: eureka ! Thank's

Answer (score 0):

OK I understand !

I've got two elements in my xsd :

```
 <xs:element name="Liaison">
       <xs:complexType />
 </xs:element>
 <xs:element name="LiaisonResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
       <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="LiaisonResult" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
```

I have changed my EndPoint :

```
@Endpoint
public class DestinataireEndpoints {

    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://www.opensolution.com/";

    @Autowired
    private DestinataireService destinataireService;    

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "Liaison")
    @ResponsePayload
    public LiaisonResponse Liaison() {
        LiaisonResponse liaisonResponse = new LiaisonResponse();
        liaisonResponse.setLiaisonResult("tests");
        return liaisonResponse;
    }
```

I receive a "Liaison" element and I return a LiaisonResponse element
and I set liaisonResult attribute with String value